# Driving two Active Monitors Off One Subwoofer Output

Tags: monitors

My question is basically whether it is okay to connect two active monitors to the same output channel on a subwoofer, including cases where only one may be on at a time? There's no weird drive issues are there?

I have my computer and piano in a L-shaped setup. My piano is to my right when I am at the piano and my computer is to my left when I am at the piano.

My two current monitors are on the left and right (hereafter shall be referred to as the center monitor) of my computer but that means both my monitors are on my left when I am at the piano. I wanted to add a third monitor to sit on the right side of my piano (hereafter which shall be referred to as the right monitor) so that I can use the left and center monitor at my computer, but use the center and right monitors at the keyboard.

The left and center speakers would be Yamaha HS7s plugged into an HS8 subwoofer. The third, right monitor would be an HS5 and would be plugged into the same output channel as the left speaker on the subwoofer. When at the piano, the left-right output channels on the sub would be reversed when I am at the piano left-channel would come out the center speaker and the right-channel would come out the right speaker.

Sometimes all speakers would be on, but other times only either the left or right speaker would be on.

Is there a problem with splitting the same output channel from a subwoofer to drive two active monitors? And is there an issue where one might be consistently powered down while the subwoofer is driving the other?

Answer (score 1):

I think your terminology is a little confused. The sub can almost be anywhere - it solely handles very low frequencies. This question isn't about connecting subwoofers.

What the HS8 has is an active crossover built in, allowing you to connect it in your speaker path to provide a sub. If you look at the back of your HS8, you'll see a circuit diagram showing this.

You can see from the diagram that the inputs connect directly to the outputs, so for the purposes of your question, all you are asking is whether you can connect two speakers onto one channel, and this comes down to impedance. The HS5 and HS7 both have an input impedance of around 10k ohms, so connecting in parallel will take that down to 5k ohms, which will increase the current draw on your amplifier... so if you tend to have your gain turned up high could cause you problems.

If you connect in series, the HS5 and HS7 will both seem quieter, but you are less likely to damage your amp through overheating.

Comment: I'm not talking about connecting in series. I'm talking about a parallel connection splitting off the connection with a Y-splitter. I also am not talking about connecting subwoofers. Did I mistype something somewhere? The connections for the Yamaha HSx is that the computer connects to the subwoofer, and the monitors connect to the sub and I am wondering if it is okay to split off either a left or right output channel from the sub to two active monitors. 10K is quite a bit lower than what I was expecting for aactive monitors though.

Comment: In reality, I think this question is offtopic here as it is not about sound design, but I have covered all those points. I know the Yamaha very well. Please re-read what I wrote, about connections, parallel and series.

Comment: Well the 10K thing tells me what I need to know. Is this off topic here? I don't really know what "Sound Design" entails but the description included enthusiasts.